# pushing, appending, << items to an array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to add items to an array but don't understand why they aren't adding.

```
considerTheseDrills = Array.new
AssignmentDrill.all.each do |ad|
  if (ignoreThese.include?(drill_id: ad.drill_id))
    puts "this one exists - ignore"
  else
    puts "doesn't exist - lets consider it"
    considerTheseDrills.push ad
    puts "why am I not getting a length? ".concat(considerTheseDrills.length)
  end
end
```

In my console I see the message saying it doesn't exist but after I add it by doing a push, I get nothing printed for the length?

I've tried `insert`, `<<` but I can't get the items to add.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this REPL session:

```
[1] pry(main)> "abc".concat(5)
=> "abc\u0005"
```

That's why you're not seeing a length.

To print the length, just interpolate it:

```
puts "why am I not getting a length? #{considerTheseDrills.length}"
```

Comment: Thanks - added .to_s and I can now see it